# I want to make json data

Tags: mysql, json, ajax, django, vue.js

There is json data as follows.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "isLeaf": false,
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "isLeaf": false,
      "name": "Node 2",
      "pid": 0,
      "disabled": true
    },
    {
      "id": "new5",
      "isLeaf": false,
      "name": "new node",
      "pid": 0,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "new7",
          "isLeaf": true,
          "name": "new leaf",
          "pid": "new5"
        },
        {
          "id": "new8",
          "isLeaf": true,
          "name": "new leaf",
          "pid": "new5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "new6",
      "isLeaf": false,
      "name": "new node",
      "pid": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make the same json data by getting the price from the DB.
If the select value is as follows:

```
id    isLeaf    name       pid     disabled
new5  false     Node2       0      null
new7  true      new leaf    new5   null
new8  true      new leaf    new5   null
```

How can I make it out of json?
How can I make it look like json above?
Please help me.

````
$.ajax({
 ```
 ??????????
 ```
});
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vue/javascript just use a .map() and a .filter() create a new array with the result and then do JSON.stringify(Array)

note: can also be a Object if you prefer